# What is the problem with new theorem environments?

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I have several theorem-like environments

```
...
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily\slshape}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Следствие}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Лемма}
\newtheorem{Def}{Определение}
\newtheorem{State}{Утверждение}
\newtheorem{Hypothesis}{Гипотеза}
...
```

But on every entry of one of these environments I got error
`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`
And it doesn't appear correctly, for example this code

```
\begin{Def}{Гауссовский процесс}
Гауссовский процесс~---случайный процесс, любая конечная совокупность сечений которого имеет совместное нормальное распределение.
\end{Def}
```

looks like [image: this]
whereas I expect at least entry of `Определение`.
What is wrong?

UPD
Providing minimum example.
I use .sty file so I list both it and main file.

style.sty:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ruled,section]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
% Параметры страницы
\textheight=24cm
\textwidth=16cm
\oddsidemargin=0mm
\topmargin=-1cm
\parindent=24pt
\tolerance=500
\footnotesep=3ex
\flushbottom
\tolerance=3000
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4} %для печати с большим интервалом

% Окружения типа теорем
\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily\slshape}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Следствие}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Лемма}
\newtheorem{Def}{Определение}
\newtheorem{State}{Утверждение}
\newtheorem{Hypothesis}{Гипотеза}
\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily}
\newtheorem{Example}{Пример}[section]
\newtheorem{Heuristic}{Эвристика}
\newtheorem{Remark}{Замечание}[section]
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %,fleqn
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{style}
\newcommand{\hdir}{.}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\section{Введение}

\subsection{Гауссовские процессы}
В качестве модели $f$ мы будем рассматривать гауссовский процесс. 
\begin{Def}[Гауссовский процесс]
Гауссовский процесс~---случайный процесс, любая конечная совокупность сечений которого имеет совместное нормальное распределение.
\end{Def}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a standard setup this shouldn't lead to any error, so whatever is happening is related to some code you are withholding. Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried with a minimal wrapper, but get no problem.

Comment: Your example  yields an example of a `Def` with an optional argument which is given between braces (`{}`), but should be between brackets (`[]`).

Comment: @campa I added the example

Comment: You are loading `amsthm` after loading `ntheorem`; the two are not exactly compatible. You may want to remove that. (In fact, as you posted, the file should not be able to be compiled successfully.) I don't have Russian installed on my system, so cannot test otherwise, but can you confirm whether the problem still persists after removing `\usepackage{amsthm}`?

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks a lot, your suggestion works!